# Cookie value to enum

Tags: vb.net, enum

Users can have a Cookie called `lang` that contains either the value "default=1" (English) or "default=2" (French). This cookie is used to determine their preferred language. I have a function that needs to take the cookie and return the language has an Enum. If the cookie doesn't exist, I want to return English. I cannot change the cookie value.

Language enum:

```
  Public Enum Language
     Undefined = 0
     English = 1
     French = 2
  End Enum
```

Function:

```
  Public Function GetLangFromCookie() As Language
     If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("lang") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim langCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("lang").Value
        Return If(langCookie(langCookie.Length - 1) = "1", Language.English, Language.French)
     End If
     Return Language.English
  End Function
```

I feel like this is not efficient and not secure but I don't know how to improve it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You query `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("lang")` twice. Access it once and store it in a variable.
- You will get a problem if in the future you have to support more than 9 languages. Instead of accessing the last char from `langCookie` you should `Split()` `langCookie` by `=` and take the second array element. You can then use `[Enum].TryParse()` to get the enum.
- Some horizontal spacing (new lines) would help to easier read the code.

Your code could look like so

```
Public Function GetLangFromCookie() As Language

    Dim langCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("lang")

    If langCookie Is Nothing Then
        Return Language.English
    Else
        Return GetLanguage(langCookie.Value)
    End If

End Function

Private Function GetLanguage(languageCookieValue As String) As Language

    Dim splittetCookieValue As String() = languageCookieValue.Split(New String() {"="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim languageIdentifier As String = splittetCookieValue.LastOrDefault()

    Dim foundLanguage As Language

    ' We don't care about the success of the TryParse() call
    [Enum].TryParse(Of Language)(languageIdentifier, foundLanguage)

    ' because foundLanguage will be 0 if it doesn't succeed and will be checked here
    Return If(foundLanguage = Language.Undefined, Language.English, foundLanguage)

End Function
```